# react-router: How to get activeClassName to work for non-exact routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Basically, I want all routes that have the same beginning substring to apply the activeClassName styles. Right now I have something like this:

```
...
return(
   <div>
      <NavLink to="/home" activeClassName={styles.Active}/>
      <NavLink to={"/articles/" + this.props.hotArticle} activeClassName={styles.Active}/>
   </div>
);
```

The NavLink to /home gets the .Active style applied to it since it's the exact route. The second NavLink to "/articles/...", however, doesn't have the same styling when I click it. How do I fix this?

Thanks yall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NavLink`'s [isActive](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func) prop function.

> A function to add extra logic for determining whether the link is
> active. This should be used if you want to do more than verify that
> the link’s pathname matches the current URL’s pathname.

Nav Links by default already do a path prefix matching, but you want to match a more general prefix. `match` and `location` are passed to the `isActive` function. Check if the match path starts with the specified route path prefix.

```
<NavLink
  activeClassName={styles.Active}
  isActive={(match) => match.path.startsWith("/articles/")}
  to={"/articles/" + this.props.hotArticle}
/>
```